# fp16 support in the Object Detection API(tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, half-precision-float

fp16 support in the Object Detection API [Feature request] · Issue #3706 · tensorflow/models
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3706

I asked on the github issue: fp16 support in the Object Detection API (tensorflow), but none of them solved the problem, so I can only come to stackoverflow for answers.
My tf version: 1.14, graphics card: Tesla T4.
[image]